# Silverlight Child Windows

Tags: silverlight

Is there a way to make a Child Window in Silverlight 3 non-draggable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joe you can alter the code (which is available at http://silverlight.codeplex.com) to create your own custom one, but there is no default setting to change that.